# UI suggestion for my own design

Tags: website-design, ux-designer

I am developing a chrome extension where I planned to show the popup with current product details and user info. So, I already constructed the popup and decided what are the things are going to showcase. And I designed my own layout :)

But the final design doesn't looks good, doesn't make the attractive look. Even I am strong in the programming, nothing strikes in my mind about the UX design. Any one can suggest me to improve the look and feel (with good colors). Thanks...

*[**Note:** not mandatory to follow the same layout, but just want to expose these informations]*

I refereed some blogs also: https://uxplanet.org/chrome-extension-popups-design-inspiration-b38de2cbd589

[image: popup image]

If I want to convert this design to material look and feel then what are the standards I should follow. or anyone suggest me about the suitable color codes..

Comment: Can you post an image of the actual popup that you have developed? Apart from just making it look good, there are other usability considerations you need to look at. However I am not sure if the image you posted is your actual implemention?

Comment: Actually this is my actual implementation only, here i am using the dummy data. This is for the JIRA products, so when I integrate this the corresponding product and user details can be exposed. Based on the permission they can perform actions.

Answer (score 3):

One important UX heuristic is to match between the system and the real world. The examples here are structured in a very system-like way.

In the user info section, consider designing this without a table -- perhaps picture first, then username, full name and email. Permissions booleans could be shown with checkboxes instead of "true/false". And if possible, maybe a human-friendly structure like:

```
[ ] Admin
[X] Read documents
[X] Delete documents
```

Good luck.

Comment: That's the good thing, here the options can't be change. But I hope we can show the tick mark based on material style... that's fine.. However I am expecting the overall UX suggestion to improve the design still. Thanks +1 :)